# jQuery, remove padding added to toggleClass element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am animating a hidden div with slideToggle.
since it has a fixed position on top, I want to add animate the padding top of that container div 'under it' with the current height of the hidden div.

However the class toggles correctly on click, and the padding is added with the correct amount of pixels, after toggling away the class the padding remains.

How come when I apply the padding on the toggled class it keeps being there even though the class is removed on 2nd click (toggling it away)?

js:

```
$('#myButton').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#myDiv').slideToggle( function(){

        var myDivHeight = $(this).outerHeight();

        $('.containerDiv').toggleClass('myDivOpened');

        $('.myDivOpened').css('padding-top', myDivHeight + 15);

    });


});
```

Thanks very much.

Comment: You add styles to an element and not to a class. Why not just add the padding to the toggled class instead?

Comment: Because the padding and class have no relationship....

Comment: ok, makes sense actually that the styles are added to the element and not to the class. but how would I go about to add padding on the toggled class, isn't that what Im doing with.
$('.myDivOpened').css('padding-top', myDivHeight + 15);

if there would be such a thing as toggleCss

Will try with hasClass. Thanks guys

Comment: So add logic to remove the padding when the class is removed.

Comment: I'm really struggling to see why you don't add that padding to a CSS class and toggle that class on and off. And plus, every time you click on `#myButton` it searches the DOM for all elements with the `myDivOpened` and `containerDiv` class, which probably isn't very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

What your method does, is adding a padding-top in the style attribute of the element in the end. It does not change the class in anyway.

Would be better to add the style in a class, yet if you really want to toggle the style with jquery, this is how it works.

```
$('.containerDiv').toggle(function () {
    $(".containerDiv").css({paddingTop: "20px"});
}, function () {
    $(".containerDiv").css({paddingTop: "0px"});
});
```

Edit:
I can see your logical problem and will try to elaborate..
First we have a div called containerDiv with no class and no padding. Then we set the class of it to myDivOpened and give all the elements of this class a paddingtop. Now what you do is removing the class again of the element containerDiv and expect it to remove the padding.

Why does it not remove the padding? Because you set it on the style attribute of containerDiv. You removed the class of it yet the style attribute is not really linked with that change and thus remains.

A proper solution would be to have two classes, one with the padding and one without and toggle between those two.

Comment: Not sure how to add the style in a class and not to an element.
I thought I did so by applying it in js to that specific class. Taking into account that the height will be variable, thats why the use of the var

Comment: First, you set the class to another element (.containerDiv) than the style (.myDivOpened). Second, .css() adds styles and does not change anything about their set classes.

Comment: Using your approach, it does toggle away the complete div, no?
http://jsfiddle.net/asturias/cLLLyrqp/

Comment: That is an effect of your slideToggle(). You could just set both elements to float left, blend them in/out and not worry about paddingTop.

Answer (score 0):

@Lain: Thanks for clarifying further. You are right, the toggle leaves the padding untouched, once inserted.

You could instead try adding and deleting the class manually.
This link may help:[api.jquery.com/toggleclass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass).

Before deleting the class, remove the padding from the class manually, then delete the class from the body.

Just pasting in some code which may help:

```
$(this).click(function(e)
{
    if (!added)
    {
        $("body").addClass("myDivOpened");
        $('.myDivOpened').css('padding-top',15);
        added = true;
    } else {
        $('.myDivOpened').css('padding-top',0);
        $("body").removeClass("myDivOpened");
        added = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Where exactly does your code remove the paddingTop again?

Comment: Theres no need to remove the padding separately.The padding has been linked as a property of the class.When you toggle the class all the properties associated with the class till now should also disappear.

Comment: In which way did you link the paddingTop property to the class?

Comment: How can I add the property to a class that hasn't been added?

Comment: @ET: Log theses linesa few times in a row in your console and see what happens with your padding - $('.myDivOpened').css('padding-top', 15);
$('body').toggleClass('myDivOpened');
$('body').css('padding-top');

Comment: @Lain : Thanks for the clarification. Have edited my answer. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have found a way to do so, since many ways lead to Rome, I'm guessing this one is valid as any other (or at least hoping it is).

```
$('#myButton').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

     var $myDiv = $('#myDiv');
     var $containerDiv = $('.containerDiv');
     var myDivHeight = $myDiv.outerHeight();

     $myDiv.toggleClass('opened');     

    $myDiv.slideToggle( function(){

        if($myDiv.hasClass('opened')){
            $containerDiv.css('padding-top', myDivHeight);
        }else{
            $containerDiv.css('padding-top', 0);
        }

    });

});
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asturias/cLLLyrqp/4/)